# Second Derivatives to Second Differences

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, intuition, laplacian

In these two videos...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLkz5LGWihw

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ly4S0oi3Yz8

...Grant shows how second derivative of $f(x)$ at some point $(x_0)$ are related to the "second differences" of the functoin.

Mathematically written:

$$[f(x_0 +dx) - f(x_0)]+[f(x_0-dx)-(f(x_0))] \propto \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}(x_0)$$

I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding this...if someone could please explain it, I'd really, really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: @NamanKumar why is the second derivative at a point (for which the only interpretation I have is that its the slope of the slope) perfectly proportional to the second difference at that point as we consider really small distances?